# C# GetType() called on multimensional array results in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to C# and looking at arrays.

I'm wondering why the call to `i.GetType()` results in a `NullReferenceException` (Object reference not .....) ?

```
       int[][] myJagArray = new int[5][];
       foreach (int[] i in myJagArray) { Console.WriteLine(i.GetType()); }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Because you declared an array, but didn't initialize any values.  Thus, there's nothing to box and call `GetType` on.

Comment: might as well drop that as an answer :)

Comment: @Haxx - Heh good idea. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, value types (such as `Int32`) will be initialized to their zero'ed out values.  For example:

```
int[] foo = new int[3];
```

Will create an array of 3 zeros.  Printing:

```
Console.WriteLine(foo[1].GetType().Name);
```

Would give you `Int32`.

However, an Array type is a reference type.  These are initialized to null by default.

For that reason, when you refer to the first item in `int[5][]`, which is an array, you'll get a `null` as it hasn't yet been initialized.  When you try to call `GetType()` on this, you'll see a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your second dimension is null.

Try this:

```
int[][] myJagArray = new int[5][];
myJagArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (int[] i in myJagArray) 
{
    if (i != null)
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("null");
}
```

Result of this will be:

```
System.Int32[]
null
null
null
null
```

You get first row not equal to null because we added this line:

```
myJagArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just declared you jagged array which gets `default` values as null

so you need to initialize those arrays as:

```
myJagArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 9 }; // put whatever values you want here
myJagArray[1] = new int[] { 0, 4, 6 };
myJagArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22 };
........
myJagArray[4] = new int[] {12,23,45};
```